# How to download gzip files using urllib2, without corrupting them?

Tags: python, gzip, urllib2

I'm writing a script to download gzipped XML sitemaps; the files download, but they are corrupt. The gzipped files outputted by the script are a little larger than they should be, and the decompressed files are smaller than they should be, because data is missing. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
saveAddress = "test.xml.gz"

import urllib2
import httplib
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
try:
    request = urllib2.Request("http://example.com/sitemap-general.xml.gz")
    request.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'gzip')
    request.add_header('User-agent', 'Custom UA String')
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    try:
        pageText = opener.open(request).read()
        open(saveAddress, "w").write(pageText)
        print "Crawled successfully."
    except URLError, e:
        pass    
except URLError, e:
    pass
```

Thanks for any help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: this could be shortened by about 5 lines using the beautiful python library "requests".  this isn't the problem, I think sgallen maybe right about the answer

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll look into it. I haven't used python much, so my code probably isn't too elegant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the file in binary mode:

```
open(saveAddress, "wb").write(pageText)
```